# What are the precautions to be noted when performing a Ghusl while fasting?

Tags: sawm

What are the precautions to be noted when performing a Ghusl (Full ritual bath) while fasting in the Ramadan?

There is a hadith that says during ablutions, water should not be sniffed when one is fasting. However, one of the Fard acts of Ghusl includes sniffing the water and blowing it out. So is Ghusl invalid without this? Can Ghusl be done while fasting?

Comment: I saw that very hadith, but I can't find it. I believe it say you should sniff water deeply, except when you are fasting (so you only sniff lightly)

Answer (score 4):

There is no Hadith that states that Ghusl is not allowed in Ramadan.
However concerning Sniffing it is Sunnah in Ghusl (can be omitted), and u can make it in Ramadan while fasting, only if water didn't enter your stomach, or if it entered without purpose it is OK, you can continue fasting. But if you sniffed strongly and on purpose so that water entered to your inside this will affect your fasting.

If you are an Arabic reader you can check [my source](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&lang=A&Id=51607).

Comment: Now I'm confused. According to [this](http://www.islamicacademy.org/html/Learn_Now/English/Ghusl.htm) and wikipedia, sniffing water in Ghusl is a Fardh.

Comment: @Power-Inside it is fard according to hanafi fiqh, it might be different in other madhabs.

Comment: @Power-Inside according to [this](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=14001) sniffing is Fard on Hanafi but it didn't mention to sniff strongly, you could sniff a lightly to complete the Fard, not to let the water enter your inside. So it is OK while you are fasting.

Comment: main problem isn't sniffing its gargling!!!!! What about that should you do it.